# Persistencia de disco con Fireblade, evitar llamarlo dos veces

Tags: android, firebase

No creo que sea necesario mostrarles código para que me ayuden en lo siguiente:

Tengo un inicio de sesión con firebase, y utilizo la persistencia de disco para cuando no tengo conexión a internet y así poder seguir utilizando mi app, una vez que yo inicio sesión el usuario queda activo aunque cierre la aplicación, ya que cuando vuelvo abrir la aplicación entra sin necesidad de registrarme de nuevo, eso está bien, el problema es que si coloco:

```
 "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);"
```

donde verifico el inicio de sesión, cada vez que cierre la app y entre va a verificar el inicio de sesión y va a llamar cada vez a:

```
"FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);"
```

lo cual da error ya que sólo se puede llamar una vez.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias opciones para resolver esto, obviamente que el problema surge cuando ya se tiene una instancia de la Base de datos, puedes revisar si la instancia es diferente de null de esta forma obtener la instancia y habilitar la persistencia:

```
private static FirebaseDatabase fbDB;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if(fbDB == null) {
                fbDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                fbDB.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            }
         ...
         ...
        }
```

---

Otra opción para evitar eliminar la aplicación es agregar lo mismo dentro de onResume() para obtener la instancia de `FirebaseDatabase` al regresar de background() o segundo plano:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
     if(fbDB == null) {
                    fbDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    fbDB.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, vi lo siguiente: al precionar el boton de atrás de mi dispositivo el sistema lo toma como un método finish(); para cerrar la ventana, en lo que programé yo cierro mis ventanas con el método finish(); sin embargo esto no cierra del todo la aplicación, por lo que utilicé system.exit(0); entonces cuando vuelvo a entrar ya la variable "FirebaseDatabase fbDB;" está nula, lo cual no hay problema al volver a pasar por el "fbDB.setPersistenceEnabled(true);" no sé si esté bien  pero me sirve, sin embargo utilizaré tu "if" por cualquier cosa, muchas gracias

Comment: para evitar eliminar la aplicación por medio de system.exit(0); ya que no funciona para todos los OS mejor agrega lo mismo en onResume() ve la actualización.

Comment: Ahh ok, muchas gracias has sido de mucha ayuda..